# Как в Swift получить данные из URLSession?

Tags: swift

Например, имеется такой Swift код:

```
 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            var dann = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            self.str = dann
    })
task.resume()
```

Я хочу передать полученные данные в переменную в классе.
`str` - переменная в классе.
Строка `"self.str = dann"` не передает ничего. Как правильно сделать?

Comment: println("STR = \(dann)") что пишет? Может там nil?
сначала лучше проверить if let err = error { /* handler error */ } else { /* check & process response */ }

Comment: Ответ есть тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1358790/swift-Получение-данные-по-http/1358803#1358803 , ответ актуален на 9.12.2021 xcode 13.1 swift 5.5

Answer (score 1):

`dataTaskWithURL()` имеет два аргумента

1. `url` - url полученный с сервера
2. `completionHandler` - функция, которая имеет 3 аргумента: `data: NSData`, `response: NSURLresponce`, `error: NSError`.

В аргументе `data` как раз и содержатся твои данные с сервера, которые ты запросил.

Но эти данные возвращаются в формате JSON (то есть, чтобы работать с ними, тебе надо их распарсить).

Тебе надо сделать примерно следующее:

```
var dann = []
 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            let jsonResult = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
            if let result: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray
            {
                self.dann = result
                })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Корректно это обработать будет проблематично, так как этот NSURLSession по-умолчанию производит работу в фоне. Перед запуском задачи измени очередь, в которой будет выполняться задача на главный. Либо внутри цикла отправляй задачу на установку значения твоей переменной с главной очереди. Но это более гемморойно, так как нужно будет писать всякие обзерверы и так далее...

```
            task.privateQueueConcurrencyType = .mainQueueConcurrencyType
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример с фрагментом ключевого кода для доступа к данным.

```
dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
      defer { self.dataTask = nil }
```

`Data` По факту это стандартный переменная в URL которая автоматически сохраняет данные.