# Swift Получение данные по HTTP

Tags: swift

интересует получение данных по HTTP, нашел код:

```
let task = AF.request(url).responseJSON { response in

    switch response.result {
    case .failure(let error):
        // Do whatever here
        return

    case .success:
        let responseJSON = JSON(try! response.result.get())
        if responseJSON.count != 0 {
            return responseJSON
        }
    }
}
```

Обыскал весь интернет, думал сменить либу а нет, все либы так ПРЕКРАСНО сделаны, вопрос как получить отсюда данные в данной строке "return responseJSON"

Ошибку выдает такую : Unexpected non-void return value in void function

N да, я знаю что это всё асинхронно и прочее, меня интересует любой способ написать пару строк и получить заветный результат, пробовал на данной либе и ещё на либе встроенной в Swift, шило на мыло, очень буду благодарен ответу, цель задачи получить по HTTP JSON данные и их обработать, с обработкой сам уже всё сделал, осталось понять как забрать данные из этого чуда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтоб получить значение из асинхронной функции, нужно сделать так:

К функции добавляется доп. аргумент:

```
func get_messages(login: String, completion: @escaping ((Response) -> Void)) {
```

А именно completion: `completion: @escaping ((Response) -> Void)`
Где Response - тип возвращаемой переменной, через запятую перечисление если их больше;

Там где нужно вернуть значение:

```
completion(json as! Response)
```

Имя переменной as! её тип.